# Insert variable into onClick event Google Analytics virtual pageview

Tags: javascript, onclick, google-analytics

I'm using js to get the URL of the current page which contains a hash mark because of AJAXs updates to the page

```
var hash = location.href;
```

A URL looks like `http://www.example.com/#project1`

What I need is this Google virtual pageview code to display the hash variable path only where it says `hash here`

`onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'hash here']);"`

to look like `onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/#project1']);"`

Thanks

Comment: There is no trace of jQuery code in your question.

Comment: I'm using jQuery elsewhere `$('#sharebox').attr('addthis:url', hash);` which doesn't have to do with the onClick event

Comment: I think you're looking for `window.location.hash`

Comment: @user1598086 does `window.location.hash` return only the path portion of the URL? My code is working using the hash variable.

Comment: `window.location.hash` returns what's after the `#` symbol (including it). If you want the path portion, without the hash, it's `location.path`. Both of them together would be `window.location.path + window.location.hash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
onClick="pushGA();"


function pushGA() {
     _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', (window.location.path + window.location.hash)]);
}
```

Or:

```
onClick="pushGA();"


function pushGA(path) {
     _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', ('/#'+window.location.hash)]);
}
```

Or:

```
onClick="pushGA('/#project');"


function pushGA(path) {
     _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', path]);
}
```

Comment: This will enter the entire URL I need it to be just the hash portion ie; `/#project1`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `location.hash`...

```
function track() {
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.hash]);
}
```